# Captcha on Nginx

Tags: nginx, gd

I have `oxwall v1.8.4.1` installed on a `ubuntu 14.04 server` with `LEMP stack`.
This server functions great with all other open-source software: `wordpress` & `opencart`
It has all the required `modules` installed inc. `GD` & `TrueType` support (required for `Captcha`)
For some unknown reason `Captcha` will not display.
I have plowed the web in vain - no answer.
Just to make sure I am not wrong, I reinstalled it again... 
**No captcha**.
Last night I tried a fresh install locally - on a `LAMP stack`...
`Captcha` displayed no problem...
So now I understand there is a problem with `captcha` on `nginx`.
Can anyone point me to a resolution?
Has anyone encountered such a problem?
Thank you

**EDIT**

I am getting the following errors:

```
[warn] 6487#6487: *3159 using uninitialized "rule" variable, 
request: "GET /ow_static/plugins/base/js/captcha.js HTTP/1.1"

[warn] 6487#6487: *3158 using uninitialized "rule" variable, 
request: "GET /captcha.php HTTP/1.1"
```

Ideas??

Comment: Which Catchpa are you using? Something Nginx specific or Google catchpa on a site served with Nginx? The web server is typically irrelevant to Google catchpa.

Comment: @Tim - not quite sure....it's here (if you can take a look): https://github.com/oxwall/oxwall/blob/master/captcha.php. I think it's this one: http://www.phpcaptcha.org

Comment: Ok so the problem is with that Catchpa library, which is PHP. Try Google Catchpa first. If that doesn't work you need to edit your question to give us a LOT more information. You would need to demonstrate the problem (ie link to your website), plus show us a curl or similar that demonstrates the problem. You should add Nginx access / error logs and PHP error logs that show any errors created. Right now your question is impossible to answer it's so broad.

Comment: @Tim please take a look at the edit and now I'm getting a 404 for captcha.php

Comment: Your question is far too vague. There's no web server logs. 404 is "not found", it could be the wrong URL, incorrect permissions, all kinds of things. Your logs above aren't labeled, are they PHP logs? I really think you're best off deleting your question and starting again, providing a lot more information.